# Dagger2 Use a Provider<T> for @BindsInstance

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Is it possible to bind a `Provider<T>` instead of just an instance `T`?

For example, I have this:

```kotlin
@Component()
interface Module {
  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun config(config: Config): Builder
  }
}
```

I would like to do something like this (but it doesn't work):

```kotlin
@Component()
interface Module {
  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun config(config: Provider<Config>): Builder
  }
}
```

#### What am I trying to do?

> NOTE: The Config class is immutable

I would like to be able to change the config value for different tests, e.g.

```kotlin
class Test {
  val configProvider: CustomProvider<Config>
  val classUnderTest: Provider<T>

  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    val module = DaggerModule()
      .setConfig(configProvider)
      .build()
    
    // Do other setup with module
    classUnderTest = module.getTestClassProvider()
  }

  @Test
  fun test() {
    configProvider.setValue(CONFIG_1)

    classUnderTest.get().doSomething();
  }

  @Test
  fun test2() {
    configProvider.setValue(CONFIG_2)

    classUnderTest.get().doSomething();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid having to finish building the module in each test case and then calling another function to handle finishing the setup, e.g.

```kotlin
@Before
fun setUp() {
  moduleBuilder = DaggerModule()
}


@Test
fun test() {
  val module = moduleBuilder.setConfig(CONFIG_1).build()
  finishSetup(module)

  // Do test
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any reason why you want to pass in a provider? Do you want to get a new instance every time?

Comment: Added more details to the question

Comment: You should just create a new module every time.